# Analyzer for randomly generated names

Tags: ruby

I recently wrote a name generator that uses a DTMC underneath (I asked about it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/91127/dtmc-implemented-as-a-name-word-whatever-generator-in-ruby)) and, since I'm not entirely confident I did it right, I wrote a script to check my code, or at least its output.

It works pretty well, but, being new to the language, I want to know how to make it more idiomatic. Performance boosts (in terms of speed and memory efficiency) would also be a plus, but since this is just a simple test script they're not as important.

```
# arguments: '-dDELIMITER'
if ARGV[0] == '-h'
    [
            'Should be used in the form:',
            '<invocation of name_gen.rb> | <ruby> name_gen_test.rb -d<delimiter>',
            'The delimiter MUST be specified in name_gen.rb and it MUST NOT be ``.'
    ].each { |line| puts line }
end

DELIMITER = ARGV[0] || abort('You must specify a delimiter as the sole command-line argument')

connections = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new 0 }
start = Hash.new 0

until (cur_line = STDIN.gets).nil?
    cur_line.chomp!
    individual_syllables = cur_line.split DELIMITER
    individual_syllables.each_with_index { |from, index|
        start[from] += 1 if index == 0
        connections[from][individual_syllables[index + 1] || !!false] += 1
    }
end

# % of start per syllable
# % of connections to each syllable it connected to

puts 'Start:'
total_start_count = start.values.inject(:+).to_f
max_len = start.keys.inject (0) { |memo, cur|
    (cur.length > memo) ? cur.length : memo
}
start.each { |text, percent|
    puts "  #{text.ljust max_len} : #{(percent * 100 / total_start_count).round.to_i}%"
    # Get the percent -> Truncate -> convert to string -> justify
}
puts

END_MARKER = '[end]'
puts 'Connections:'
connections.each { |from, links|
    total_connection_count = links.values.inject(:+).to_f
    max_len = links.keys.inject(END_MARKER.length) { |memo, cur|
        ((cur ? cur : '').length > memo) ? cur.length : memo
    }
    puts "  #{from}:"
    links.each { |to, probability|
        next unless to
        puts "    #{to.ljust max_len} : #{(probability * 100 / total_connection_count).round.to_i}%"
    }
    puts "    #{END_MARKER} : #{(links[false] * 100 / total_connection_count).round.to_i}%"
}
```

[This](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/newbiedoodle/RandomBits/master/MarkovNameGenerator/name_gen.rb) is the name generator; this script is meant to be used something like this (on Windows, at least):

```
ruby name_gen.rb dict.txt 10000 -d_ | ruby name_gen_test.rb _
```

if the dictionary of syllables is located at 'dict.txt'.

Here's an example dictionary file:

> ```
> a|1|1|b,2;c,2
> b|0|3|a,0;c,2
> c|0|0|a,1;b,1
> ```

And an example output for the script:

> ```
> Start:
>   a : 100%
>
> Connections:
>   a:
>     c     : 40%
>     b     : 40%
>     [end] : 20%
>   c:
>     a     : 50%
>     b     : 50%
>     [end] : 0%
>   b:
>     c     : 40%
>     [end] : 60%
> ```

For anyone interested, the final code is available [here](https://github.com/newbiedoodle/RandomBits/blob/master/MarkovNameGenerator/name_gen_test.rb).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The ruby [style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) suggests to use 2 spaces per indentation level.
2. You can use heredocs for multi-line strings, keep in mind that they preserve white space, here is a nice trick that could be used:

   ```
   help = <<-END.gsub(/^\s+\|/, '')
     |Should be used in the form:,
     |<invocation of name_gen.rb> | <ruby> name_gen_test.rb -d<delimiter>,
     |The delimiter MUST be specified in name_gen.rb and it MUST NOT be ``.
             END
   help.each_line { |line| puts line }
   ```
3. for multiline blocks please use `do...end` instead of `{...}`:

   ```
   individual_syllables.each_with_index do |from, index|
   start[from] += 1 if index == 0
   connections[from][individual_syllables[index + 1] || !!false] += 
   end
   ```
4. I don't understand why you use `!!false`, since `!!false == false`. Also I don't think it is needed here.
5. Do not put a space between a method name and the opening parenthesis:

   ```
   max_len = start.keys.inject (0)
   ```
6. *Avoid* nested ternary operators, it makes the code hard to understand.

   ```
   ((cur ? cur : '').length > memo) ? cur.length : memo
   # becomes
   cur ||= ''
   [cur.length, memo].max
   ```

Comment: I used `!!false` because RubyMine kept giving me a warning if I tried to use just `!!false`. The four spaces are actually tabs that I converted to the default so that StackOverflow wouldn't complain. For #6, would `[(cur || '').length, memo].max` also be fine? I'd prefer to keep it to one line if possible. Aside from that, once I get a chance, I'll apply these changes, test a bit, and accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Er, typo: It gave me a warning if I tried to use just `false`. Looking back at it, I'm not sure it's necessary; I could just change `links[false]` to `links[nil]` and that whole bit goes away.

Comment: bbatsov's guide sucks

Comment: @Nakilon actually it's a comunity driven guide. I don't see why someone would dislike such style.

Comment: @Mhmd, community was enough careful to not make any (potentinally bad) style propaganda, until the least careful kid made his awful snippet of bad advises. Now community have to spend years on making it less awful -- this *correction* produces so awesomely pointless rules like: "Q: do I write P or R? A: write P, or R."

Comment: @Nakilon After seeing "Use **two spaces** per indentation level (aka soft tabs). No hard tabs." I'm inclined to agree. I like tabs because it's a rendering option to change how wide they look, so while I think four is prettier, someone who think two or eight or nine point eight four is prettier could easily change it to that, and no one else's copy would be change to something they dislike. Of course, other people are free to use spaces -- that's their choice -- but don't get all bossy when I change it to four because I have a big screen and you feel jealous.

Comment: @Mhmd Alright, I applied (most of) the changes you noted, except for #1 (see previous comment) and #4, since I need to test that before committing it and I can't currently. Thanks for the help.